# Node in three dimensions with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am using `pgfplots` to draw a curve in three dimensions. I've placed a point on this curve, and would now like to obtain the following two:

- The node's name should appear below the node;
- I would like to choose the filling color and outer color of the node independently.

This is generally not a problem in 2D-tikz, but I'm having trouble to find anything useful for three dimensions.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[mark=*,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] coordinates {(0,-1,0)[$x$]};
            \addplot3[variable=t,domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(t))},{cos(deg(t))},0);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly. This can be achieved by:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[
            mark=*,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={below},
            every mark/.append style={draw=red,fill=red!20},
            ] coordinates {(sin(deg(5)),cos(deg(5),0)[$x$]};
            \addplot3[variable=t,domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(t))},{cos(deg(t))},0);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```